# EXCEL VBA assigning values to multiple vairables

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba

hi i am trying to insert a values from excel to mysql database. so my values are in row. about 20+ cells per row. and each cell must be inputted to a specific column in database.

what i need is a simplified code of what i have.

```
SQLStr = "INSERT INTO submitteddrawings(Team,Name,MgtNo,JobNo,DrawingNo,Status,Version,SubMo,DwgSheet,ReusedDwg,PCChecked, N1A,N1B,N1C,N1D,N2A,N2B,N2C,N2D,N3A,N3B,N3C,N3D,N3E,N4A,N4B,N4C,N4D,N4E,N5A,N5B,N5C,N5D,N6,J1A,J1B,J1C,J2A,J2B,J2C,J2D,J2E,J3A,J3B,J3C,J3D,J3E,J3F,J3G) VALUES ('" & e & "', '" & f & "','" & g & "','" & h & "','" & i & "','" & j & "','" & k & "','" & l & "','" & m & "','" & n & "','" & o & "','" & p & "','" & q & "','" & r & "','" & s & "','" & t & "','" & u & "','" & v & "','" & w & "','" & x & "','" & y & "','" & z & "','" & aa & "','" & ab & "','" & ac & "','" & ad & "','" & ae & "','" & af & "','" & ag & "','" & ah & "','" & ai & "','" & aj & "', '" & ak & "','" & al & "','" & am & "','" & an & "','" & ao & "','" & ap & "','" & aq & "','" & ar & "','" & ass & "','" & at & "','" & au & "','" & av & "','" & aw & "','" & ax & "','" & ay & "','" & az & "','" & ba & "','" & bb & "','" & bc & "','" & bd & "')"
```

as seen there are plenty and eye irritating variables. 
TIA

Comment: You could (and should) use a prepared statement for the insert.  This would at least get rid of those single concatenated quotes everywhere.  For a further simplification, if you were assigning values to every column in your MySQL table, you might also be able to eliminate the column names, though it's probably safer to leave them there.

Comment: thanks for the additional idea. so basically this is the only and simpliest way we can have? is looping a possible option?

Comment: Of course you can loop, if your insert logic would allow for that.  But if you just have say 10 ad-hoc inserts with no relation, then you'd need code for those 10 inserts.

Comment: would you be so kind to give sample of the loop sir? sorry i am very new to this. i dont honestly even know that ad-hoc is LOL

Comment: I don't know VBA, but even if I did, I couldn't give you a loop because you never gave us logic for what you want to insert.  Read up on prepared statements in VBA, and Stack Overflow is a good place to start.

Comment: sorry, the logic of what i'm trying to do is, for each cell in range("E7:BD7"), cell(1,0) insert it to column(Team), cell(1,1) is to column(Name), and so on. as of now i assigned variables to each cell in range. and have it on my prepared string query.

Answer (score 1):

Try understand what below does - Creates a String for a specific range in a row. This is just on of many ways to achieve generating SQL statements for a specific range in Excel.

```
Option Explicit

Private Function GetInsertStatementForRowRange(InputRange As Range) As String
    Dim SQLStr As String, sValues As String, oRng As Range
    Const INSERT_BASE As String = "INSERT INTO submitteddrawings(Team,Name,MgtNo,JobNo,DrawingNo,Status,Version,SubMo,DwgSheet,ReusedDwg,PCChecked,N1A,N1B,N1C,N1D,N2A,N2B,N2C,N2D,N3A,N3B,N3C,N3D,N3E,N4A,N4B,N4C,N4D,N4E,N5A,N5B,N5C,N5D,N6,J1A,J1B,J1C,J2A,J2B,J2C,J2D,J2E,J3A,J3B,J3C,J3D,J3E,J3F,J3G) VALUES (<VALUES>)"
    sValues = ""
    For Each oRng In InputRange.Cells
        If Len(sValues) > 0 Then sValues = sValues & ", "
        sValues = sValues & "'" & oRng.Value & "'"
    Next
    SQLStr = Replace(INSERT_BASE, "<VALUES>", sValues)
    GetInsertStatementForRowRange = SQLStr
End Function

Sub SO45427529()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Const COLS_BASE As String = "E<R>:BD<R>"
    ' Below example is just for columns E to BD on row 2 of ActiveSheet
    ' You need to modify the Do-Loop to suit your useful range, assuming stop when it's empty
    lRow = 7 ' Start from row 7
    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(lRow, "E"))
        ' Observe the output in Immediate Window
        Debug.Print "Row " & lRow, GetInsertStatementForRowRange(Range(Replace(COLS_BASE, "<R>", lRow)))
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples of how you can create a function to wrap the Values.

### Example 1:

Convert the values of the row into a 1 Dimensional array and use Join to create a string that wraps the individual values

```
Function getSingleQuotedValues(Target As Range)
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Target.Value)
    Data = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Data)
    getSingleQuotedValues = "'" & Join(Data, "','") & "'"
End Function
```

### Example 2 MYSQL:

This will allow you more flexibility when working with the values by using a `Select Case` statement to decide how the individual columns' data is formatted.

Output

```
'1/2/2009  6:17:00 AM','Product1','1200','Mastercard','carolina','Basildon','England','United Kingdom','1/2/2009  6:00:00 AM','1/2/2009  6:08:00 AM','51.5','-1.1166667','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48','49','50','51','52','53','54','55','56'
```

---

```
Function getMySQLValues(Target As Range) As String
    Dim r As Range
    Dim s As String
    For Each r In Target
        Select Case r.Column
            Case 1, 9, 10
                s = s & ",'" & Format(r.Value, "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS") & "'"    'Columns containing Date values
            Case Else
                s = s & ",'" & r.Value & "'"
        End Select
    Next
    getMySQLValues = Right(s, Len(s) - 1)
End Function
```

### Bonus get Access Values string:

Output

```
#20090102061700#,'Product1',1200,'Mastercard','carolina','Basildon','England','United Kingdom',#20090102060000#,#20090102060800#,51.5,-1.1166667,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56
```

---

```
Function getAccessValues(Target As Range) As String
    Dim r As Range
    Dim s As String
    For Each r In Target
        Select Case r.Column
            Case 2, 4 To 8                            'Columns containing String values
                s = s & ",'" & r.Value & "'"
            Case 1, 9, 10
                s = s & ",#" & Format(r.Value, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss") & "#"    'Columns containing Date values
            Case Else                                 'Columns containing Numeric values
                s = s & "," & r.Value
        End Select
    Next
    getAccessValues = Right(s, Len(s) - 1)
End Function
```

### Test

```
Sub Test()
    Dim x As Long

    With Worksheets("Data")
        Debug.Print "Test getSingleQuotedValues"
        For x = 2 To 5
            Debug.Print getSingleQuotedValues(.Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Range("A1:BD1"))
        Next

        Debug.Print vbCrLf & "Test getAccessValues"
        For x = 2 To 5
            Debug.Print getAccessValues(.Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Range("A1:BD1"))
        Next

        Debug.Print vbCrLf & "Test getMySQLValues"
        For x = 2 To 5
            Debug.Print getMySQLValues(.Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Range("A1:BD1"))
        Next

    End With
End Sub
```